# Splitting a html table in a foreach c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate a html table, and after each 25 rows I want to split it and start a new table. The problem is c# is able to see my html code inside the `foreach` loop, and regards it as broken code. what is the workaround for this?

```
@{
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (var collection in Model.Collections)
    {
        if (counter % 25 == 0)
        {
            </tbody></table>
                <table class='table table__next'> 
                  <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>37.18.3019</td>
                    <td>c21351900000055</td>
                    <td>nope</td>
                    <td>888ml</td>
                    <td>154.8 g/l</td>
                    <td>165/88</td>
                    <td>189754</td>
                    <td>9999/99 99.99.9999</td>
                </tr>
        } else {
                <tr>
                <td>37.18.3019</td>
                <td>c21351900000055</td>
                <td>nope</td>
                <td>888ml</td>
                <td>154.8 g/l</td>
                <td>165/88</td>
                <td>189754</td>
                <td>9999/99 99.99.9999</td>
            </tr>
        }
            counter++;
    }
}
```

Current result: https://prnt.sc/pvw1st

Comment: What you need? is your table not populating ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 
`Html.Raw("</tbody></table>")`

With Html.Raw() function you can write any string into the html, without parsing errors.

Comment: Thanks, I tested out few responses and this turned out to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @Html.Raw

```
<table>
<tbody>       
@{
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var collection in Model.Collections)
        {
            if (counter % 25 == 0)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</tbody></table><table><tbody>");
            }
            <tr>
                <td>37.18.3019</td>
                <td>c21351900000055</td>
                <td>nope</td>
                <td>888ml</td>
                <td>154.8 g/l</td>
                <td>165/88</td>
                <td>189754</td>
                <td>9999/99 99.99.9999</td>
            </tr>
            counter++;
        }
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and you need to check counter must be bigger than zero. Because (0 %25 == 0) returns true. And it will create empty table first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `@:` syntax or a `<text>` tag](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) to indicate to the Razor engine that this is content to be emitted and not server-side code.  For example:

```
if (counter % 25 == 0)
{
    <text>
        </tbody></table>
        <table class='table table__next'> 
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>37.18.3019</td>
                    <td>c21351900000055</td>
                    <td>nope</td>
                    <td>888ml</td>
                    <td>154.8 g/l</td>
                    <td>165/88</td>
                    <td>189754</td>
                    <td>9999/99 99.99.9999</td>
                </tr>
    </text>
}
```

Or:

```
if (counter % 25 == 0)
{
    @:</tbody></table>
    @:<table class='table table__next'> 
    @:    <tbody>
    @:        <tr>
    @:            <td>37.18.3019</td>
    @:            <td>c21351900000055</td>
    @:            <td>nope</td>
    @:            <td>888ml</td>
    @:            <td>154.8 g/l</td>
    @:            <td>165/88</td>
    @:            <td>189754</td>
    @:            <td>9999/99 99.99.9999</td>
    @:        </tr>
}
```

(The latter is usually only used for single-line outputs, and the former for larger blocks, but both are shown here for completeness.)

To make use of server-side code within these blocks, you'd use the same `@` syntax you use anywhere:

```
<text>
    <p>This is a server-side value: @myValue</p>
</text>
```

Comment: I tried it out but the <text></text> did not work for me. I used it just as you show but for some reason I kept getting syntax errors: https://prnt.sc/pvy5lg Html.raw turned out to be the best solution. But thanks anyway